# Will not update record in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

My problem right now:
No values are getting updated on a specific ID as specified (hardcoded) in the WHERE clause.

**Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?**

I have a form with about 7 fields to fill out. Currently, I am just trying to get the code to work with a hardcoded SQL query like `WHERE fanID=2` then I will get it to work later with session variables.

I have (3) files:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" id="FanDetail">
  <textarea id="bio" name="fan_bio" />
  <input id="dob" name="fan_dob" />
  <input id="actualZip" />
  <input id="actualOccup" />
  <input id="fbkurl" />
  <input id="twiturl" />
  <input id="phoNum" />
</form>
```

**a `JS` file, linked to in the `HTML` file:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#FanDetail").submit(function() {
    // store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
    var bio = $('#bio').attr('value');
    var dob = $('#dob').attr('value');
    var zip = $('#actualZip').attr('value');
    var occup = $('#actualOccup').attr('value');
    var fbkurl = $('#fbkurl').attr('value');
    var twiturl = $('#twiturl').attr('value');
    var phoNum = $('#phoNum').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../../php/registration/about/submitvalues_about_tab.php",
        data: "bio="+ bio +"&amp; dob="+ dob +"&amp; zip="+ zip +"&amp; occup="+ occup +"&amp; fbkurl="+ fbkurl +"&amp; twiturl="+ twiturl +"&amp; phoNum="+ phoNum,
        success: function(){
            $('form#FanDetail').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

**A PHP file, that is linked to by the above JS File:**

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
######## Get  Input to Submit ############## //
///////////////////////////////////////////////
$fanBio =       $_POST['fan_bio'];       //////
$fanDob =       $_POST['fan_dob'];       //////
$zipval =       $_POST['actualzipval'];  //////
$occupval =     $_POST['actualOccupval'];//////
$facebookurl =  $_POST['fan_fbk'];       //////
$twitterurl =   $_POST['fan_twit'];      //////
$phoneNum =     $_POST['fan_pho'];       //////
///////////////////////////////////////////////

try{
    ## Get current user and their session ID:
    $sessionvar = session_id();
    ### DB Connection already established above.
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  

    // INSERT CLEAN DATA INTO TABLE…
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("
    UPDATE Fan 
    SET fanBio=?,fanDob=?,fanDetLocID=?,occupID=?,fanFbk=?,fanTwit=?,fanPho=?
    WHERE fanID=2
    ");
    $sth->bindParam(1,$fanBio);
    $sth->bindParam(2,$fanDob);
    $sth->bindParam(3,$zipval);
    $sth->bindParam(4,$occupval);
    $sth->bindParam(5,$facebookurl);
    $sth->bindParam(6,$twitterurl);
    $sth->bindParam(7,$phoneNum);
    $sth->execute();
} 

catch(PDOException $e){
file_put_contents('../../../../PDODBConnectionErrors.txt','ERROR: [submitvalues_about_tab.php] about '.$e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);  
}
```

I'm quite new to jQuery `.ajax()`, so go easy on me.

However, I'ved trouble shooting:

- Check error log in the `catch{}` above - was initialially getting errors with my query, but I had fixed them and **NOTHING** appears in it anymore.
- Tested query itself by hardcoding values - **inputs fine**.
- Checked to make sure `jquery file/php file` are **linked properly -> they are**.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get an error from the database?  Are you sure that the query is being sent to the database?  If so, then if the update is failing, there should be an error message.

Comment: Your $_POST values in your PHP script called in ajax are wrong. Their names should correspond to the ones you indicated in your "data", so for instance, $_POST['bio'] instead of $_POST['fan_bio'].
Also, you should use .val() instead of .attr('value');

Comment: yes that is definitely an issue

Comment: Also, is the PHP script even being reached? Is the success function in your AJAX call ever called?

Comment: Are you sure thats correct? I though `$_POST` used the value of the name attribute.

Comment: Yes, success is called and it hides the form. Just none of the data is retrieved.

Comment: They do if you treat your form in another form (like after submitting in). But in this case, the $_POST variables are not from the form submission directly but from the ajax call. This means the $_POST array corresponds to the "data:" in the ajax call.

Comment: Plus, his inputs don't have any names... He just retrieves their values in javascript before passing them to the ajax query.

Comment: So how is it working after changing your $_POST keys?

Comment: They do have names, i just didnt include them.

Comment: Ok, well anyways, you have to use the names you gave in data, so bio, dob, zip, occup, ...

Comment: What error do you have exactly?

Comment: The error: I cannot even submit anymore. Thus, it isnt firing off the success() event anymore... Did you see the updated code above?

Comment: The file in try{} is blank, so it has to be something with either the JS vars or Php Vars I would think?

Comment: Yes, can you:
1- show the exact form code
2- try to alert / console.log your variables in your javascript code to check their values

Comment: try commenting your ajax query and alert("bio="+ bio +"&amp; dob="+ dob +"&amp; zip="+ zip +"&amp; occup="+ occup +"&amp; fbkurl="+ fbkurl +"&amp; twiturl="+ twiturl +"&amp; phoNum="+ phoNum); instead, to check if your url is correct, then if it is, check if it enters the try{}catch{} in your php script

Comment: Good idea, doing so did output everything I inputted....

Comment: It outputted: bio=Developer Site&amp; dob=11/26/1958&amp; zip=30232&amp; occup=5&amp; fbkurl=joe123&amp; twiturl=joe12345&amp; phoNum=8261234567

Comment: So the url is correct and your form is actually submitted. Now you have to debug your ajax query. Check if you enter the catch{}, and if so, paste the error.

Comment: You can also try something like "echo 'something';" in your php script, and update your success like this: success(msg){ alert(msg) };
This will tell you if your script is called. Then depending on where you put your "echo", you can check if you enter the try{} block or not

Comment: Do *not* change the nature of the question; it invalidates those that have answered already.  If you have a *truly different question*, then ask a *separate question*.  Stack Overflow is not a rolling debugging resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion - .post() and serialize() to minimize your code a little:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#FanDetail").submit(function() {       
        $.post(
            "../../../php/registration/about/submitvalues_about_tab.php",
            $("form#FanDetail").serialize(),
            function(){
                $('form#FanDetail').hide(function(){
                    $('div.success').fadeIn();
            });
          });
       return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: So, this would essentially replace this existing code: `$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../../../php/registration/about/submitvalues_about_tab.php",
  data: "bio="+ bio +"&amp; dob="+ dob +"&amp; zip="+ zip +"&amp; occup="+ occup +"&amp; fbkurl="+ fbkurl +"&amp; twiturl="+ twiturl +"&amp; phoNum="+ phoNum,
  success: function(){
   $('form#FanDetail').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
   }
  });
 return false;
 });
});`     ?

Comment: Yep! .serialize() will also minimize the possibility that you've spelled something wrong, and the nice part is if you add a new field to the form you won't need to modify your jQuery code.

Generally speaking, unless you need to do something more complex, you shouldn't have to directly call $.ajax(). Use $.post() and $.get() if you can (both are just shorthand methods for .ajax()). 

Also, for suture reference, if you're ever trying to retrieve JSON from the server, use $.getJSON().

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: This is indeed a good idea, and it will prevent you from using differents keys in your $_POST when in your php script called in ajax, which got you confused in the first place =)

Comment: Can you let me know how I should now modify my keys? I'm not following that part...

Comment: How does this code offered by @R2-Bacca ever get the values of the form element like zip="+zip ?

Comment: @user975947 - .serialize() takes every input between the opening and closing forms tags and puts the values into a submit-able string like `blah.php?whatever=1&something=5` from a form that had `<input name="whatever" /> <input name="something" />`

Comment: It seems to grab the form data fine. `fan_bio:dev at place
fan_dob:11/26/1958
term:Kauffield, NJ`. The databases value just STILL doesnt `update`.

Comment: try `$sth->debugDumpParams();` after your `$sth->execute()` and see if the SQL query looks wrong.

Comment: I'm running this: `$sth->bindParam(7,$phoneNum);
 $sth->execute();
 $sth->debugDumpParams(); ## debugging query` . After I submit it, it just `hide()` the form and says `Got it` . Where is the result of `debugDumpParams()` supposed to be because I dont see it in Javascript Console in Chrome

Comment: I got this in response: `Params:  7
Key: Position #0:
paramno=0
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #1:
paramno=1
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #2:
paramno=2
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #3:
paramno=3
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #4:
paramno=4
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #5:
paramno=5
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #6:
paramno=6
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2`

Comment: In addition to: `SQL: [107] 
 UPDATE Fan 
 SET fanBio=?,fanDob=?,fanDetLocID=?,occupID=?,fanFbk=?,fanTwit=?,fanPho=?
 WHERE fanID = 1`

Comment: If I input actual values in for each field like `fanBio='Hi There', fanDob=11/26/1958, fanDetLocID=2034`...etc and run on mysql, it updates the row..

Comment: But, not via the form. Thoughts?

Comment: It seems as though the params are not binding properly... try using bindVal() instead of bindParam().

Comment: `$sth->bindVal(1,$fanBio);
 $sth->bindVal(2,$fanDob);
 $sth->bindVal(3,$zipval);
 $sth->bindVal(4,$occupval);
 $sth->bindVal(5,$facebookurl);
 $sth->bindVal(6,$twitterurl);
 $sth->bindVal(7,$phoneNum);
 $sth->execute();` This doesnt work out any different than before.

Comment: `$sth->bindValue(3,$zipval);
 $sth->bindValue(4,$occupval);
 $sth->bindValue(5,$facebookurl);
 $sth->bindValue(6,$twitterurl);
 $sth->bindValue(7,$phoneNum);
 $sth->execute();`     ****

Comment: bindValue()...my bad.. sorry.

Comment: Im using this: `$sth->bindValue(4,$occupval,PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $sth->bindValue(5,$facebookurl,PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sth->bindValue(6,$twitterurl,PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $sth->bindValue(7,$phoneNum,PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $sth->execute();`

Comment: The problem is, it doesnt submit the values to the database -- still

Comment: Still getting output like: `SQL: [107] 
 UPDATE Fan 
 SET fanBio=?,fanDob=?,fanDetLocID=?,occupID=?,fanFbk=?,fanTwit=?,fanPho=?
 WHERE fanID = 1
 
Params:  7
Key: Position #0:
paramno=0
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #1:
paramno=1
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #2:
paramno=2
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #3:
paramno=3
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #4:
paramno=4
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #5:
paramno=5
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #6:
paramno=6
name=[0] ""
is_param=1`